# Uniform continuity of the function $x(t)=e^{tA}x$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$. Consider the exponential function $x(t)=e^{tA}x:=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{t^nA^n}{n!}x$, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, where $x\in X$. If the function $t\mapsto x(t)=e^{tA}x$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ then it is uniformly continuous. In fact $x(t)$ is a solution of the ordinary differential equation
$$x'(t)=Ax(t).$$
It follows that 
$$x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^tAx(u)du.$$
Then $$\left|x(t)-x(s) \right|=\left|\int_s^tAx(u)du\right|\leq  \left|A\right| \left|x\right|_\infty \left|t-s\right|.$$

So $x(t)$ is even Lipshitz.

We can visualize this intuitively in the case $X=\mathbb{R}$, the function $x(t)=e^{ta}x$ is bounded if and only if $a$ is pure imaginary, so $x(t)$ has the form $\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)$ which is uniformly continuous.

My question concerns the case when $A$ is an unbounded operator which generates a [strongly continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) group of operators $(T(t))_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$. We consider now the function $x(t)=T(t)x$. I tried to do the same manipulations as the function $t\mapsto e^{tA}x$. From some properties of strongly continuous groups we have $\int_0^tT(u)xdu\in D(A)$ for all $x\in X$, where $D(A)$ is the domain of $A$. In addition
$$x(t)=T(t)x=x+A\int_0^tT(u)xdu=x+A\int_0^tx(u)du$$
Using this I tried
$$\left|x(t)-x(s) \right|=\left|A\int_s^tx(u)du\right|.$$
But I stopped here since $A$ is not bounded.
So my question is what can we say in this case ? is $x(t)=T(t)x$ uniformly continuous if it is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I guess you assume the semigroup is defined only for nonnegative $t$?

Comment: @timur Here I consider the case of strongly continuous groups, so $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is defined on the whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question. My answer does not adress it.

---

Consider e.g. the translation group on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. These operators are isometries and thus the group is bounded, it is however not uniformly continuous.

This and more examples can be found on pp. 34 in [the book of Engel and Nagel](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf).

---

Comment: For a fixed $x$, $\|U(t)x-U(s)x\|=\|(I-U(s-t))x\|$ looks uniformly continuous to me.

Comment: The OP obviously considers uniform continuity of $t\mapsto T(t)x$ while I was adressing $t\mapsto T(t)$.

Comment: $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is the only uniform continuity you can have for the case of an unbounded generator. Just continuity (not even uniform continuity) of $t\mapsto T(t)$ implies a bounded generator.

Comment: You have to specify the topoogy you are using on $\cal{L}(X)$. If you use the uniform operator topology some people cf. the above book Def. 3.6 call $t\mapsto T(t)$ uniformly continuous. Anyhow, deleting my wrong answer would delete your correct comments. Therefore I have added an edit to the answer.

Comment: I don't mind if you delete my comments, but thank you for being so courteous. I've have people change the entire question after I've answered their question and it made it look like my answer had nothing to do with anything. That's about the only thing that ever bothers me in this forum. People are mostly all just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @T.A.E.  Following your argument, this means that the counterexample (if it exists) must be an unbounded group i.e. $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}|U(t)|=+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand. So you have an unbounded group, but a vector x for which U(t)x is uniformly bounded. Seems plausible that might give you uniform continuity for t↦U(t)x in the norm topology, but I don't know.